# GSAP master-timeline not working correctly when shared via Pinia in Vue/Nuxt

Tags: nuxt.js, vuejs3, gsap, pinia, nuxt3

I'm relatively new to Vue and GSAP, and I'm running into a problem that I'm not sure is related to Vue or GSAP. I have created a simplified example on StackBlitz to demonstrate the problem: [**example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nuxt-starter-betrtj?file=app.vue).

Master timeline -> stores/AnimationStore.ts 
Usage & Child timeline -> app.vue

---

Here is the problem I'm facing: I'm trying to share a GSAP timeline called master via Pinia in my Nuxt 3 project. Components in the project can create their own child timelines and add them to the master timeline. In the example, the child timeline is correctly added to the master timeline, but when I play the master timeline, it just starts (console.log('Master started')), but doesn't update or finish. Also, the child timeline doesn't run.

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions on how to solve this issue. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: If you're just starting it might be better to use Options Stores instead of Composition Stores. Read [which syntax should I pick](https://pinia.vuejs.org/core-concepts/#what-syntax-should-i-pick). Note this is only valid for stores. not for components. Components benefit a lot from Composition. Stores... not so much (concerns should already be separated in stores).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your `stores/AnimationStore.ts` change `reactive` to `shallowRef`

Comment: Consider explaining why ([give a man a fish...](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/give_a_man_a_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_day;_teach_a_man_to_fish_and_you_feed_him_for_a_lifetime)).

Comment: @tao it's hard to explain this it's like he's putting the fish in another basket and i'm showing him to put it back in his own basket

Comment: This solves the problem. Thanks a lot. Will read the docs again.

Comment: It's because GSAP timeline is a class. Reactivity doesn't mix with classes and `shalloRef` does exactly thiat: it tells Vue, *"don't add reactivity deeper into this thing"*.